# Model_TH3D_v3 on uproot4

Tags: uproot

I am trying to import a TH3 v3 file from .root, but I get the following error message:

```
----> 3 a=fileRCL[filename].to_numpy()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uproot/behaviors/TH3.py in to_numpy(self, flow, dd)
    100         """
    101         values = self.values(flow=flow)
--> 102         xedges = self.edges(0)
    103         yedges = self.edges(1)
    104         zedges = self.edges(2)

AttributeError: 'Model_TH3D_v3' object has no attribute 'edges'
```

As you can see, the object is accessible from root browser and has the edges.

[image: original file]

Any idea?
uproot4
Ubuntu 20.04
vscode insider 1.52
conda 4.9.2
python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, caused by interface changes needed to adopt to [Scikit-HEP's unified histogram protocol](https://github.com/scikit-hep/boost-histogram/issues/423) while not explicitly testing TH3 (3-dimensional histograms) because I didn't have any examples in [scikit-hep-testdata](https://github.com/scikit-hep/scikit-hep-testdata).

Can you confirm that [scikit-hep/uproot4#239](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot4/pull/239) fixes your issue? Thanks!

Comment: It is fixed from version 4.0.11 onwards.